# Suspicious proof of continuous mapping theorem on random variables

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

My textbook has this theorem:

> Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ converges in probability to a random variable $X$ and that $h$ is a continuous function. Then $h(X_1), h(X_2),\cdots$ converges in probability to $h(X)$

Failed to come up with a proof immediately, I looked at the proof provided in the [solution](http://exampleproblems.com/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf):

> If $h$ is continuous, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exits $\delta>0$ such that $|h(x_n)−h(x)| < \epsilon$  for $|x_n−x| < \delta$. Since $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ converges in probability to the random variable $X$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|X_n − X| < \delta) = 1$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|h(X_n) − h(X)| < \epsilon) = 1$.

The part follows "since" does not really make sense to me. I think the subtly lies in the fact that $X_n$ is a random variable (that is, a function defined on some sigma-algebra $\Omega$). So for a given $\omega \in \Omega$, for a given $n$, and for a given $\epsilon >0$, we indeed can find $\delta$ such that
$$|X_n( \omega) - X (\omega)| < \delta \text{ implies that } |h(X_n( \omega) - h(X (\omega))|<\epsilon$$

, but the choice of such $\delta$ seems to depend on $\omega$ and $n$? My expectation was that, in the end, we want something like
$$\{\omega\in \Omega: |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|<\delta\} \subset \{ \omega\in\Omega: |h(X_n(\omega) - h(X(\omega))| < \epsilon\}$$

Comment: What were the exact hypotheses on $h$.  In particular, do they assume $h$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: @kimchilover Well, it doesn't say uniformly continuous in the theorem.

Comment: Look at the wikipedia article on [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability).  It's clear that your textbook's "proof" is an abridgment of the argument given there.  I'm not 100% sure of the details of the wikipedia argument, but it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: The claimed proof is wrong because the statement "given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|h(x_n)−h(x)| < \epsilon$ for $|x_n - x| < \delta$" is not generally true for continuous functions; it's the definition of *uniformly continuous*.  But if $h$ were uniformly continuous the proof would be fine.  The $\delta$ really does only depend on $\epsilon$ and not on anything else in sight.  The choice to call the second point $x_n$ is perhaps part of the confusion; they should have written "$|h(y) - h(x)| < \epsilon$ for $|x-y| < \delta$."

Comment: You can use `\implies` or even `\iff` instead of `\text{ implies that }`

Comment: @NateEldredge Just to be clear, "the $\delta$ really does only depend on $\epsilon$ and not on anything else" is true only when we have uniform continuity, correct?

Comment: @Misakov: Yes, correct.  If $h$ is merely continuous then $\delta$ also depends on $x$.

Comment: Casella Berger, Theorem 5.5.4 for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is right: the "proof" in the book is incomplete.  It assumes $h$ is *uniformly continuous*, that is, that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a single $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ the usual good stuff happens.  The proof sketched in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability) is more serious, if hard to follow.  My library does not have a copy of the book the wikipedia's proof seems taken from, so I came up with a separate argument, which is (I think) a bit more conceptual than the wikipedia's argument, or at least relies on standard facts in a more self-evident way.

These facts are: in a  separable metric space $(S,d)$, convergence in probability is metrizable by the metric $d_P(X,Y)=E\min(1,d(X,Y))$, and in a  separable metric space, convergence in probability $X_n\xrightarrow P  X$ implies convergence in distribution $X_n\xrightarrow D X$.  See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) or the discussion in Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*, (first, 1968 edition) p.26.

Here is a sketch of how to use them to prove the result.  We have  $X_n\xrightarrow{P}X,$ where the rvs are $S$-valued, and $h:S\to S'$ is continuous.   Then we also have $(X_n,X)\xrightarrow{P}(X,X)$
and $(X_n,X)\xrightarrow{D}(X,X)$.  (The first follows from use of $d_P$; the second is standard.) Define  $g:S\times S\to \mathbb R$ by $g(u,v) = \max(1,d(h(u),h(v)))$, where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the metric on $S'$.  It is clear that $g$ is continuous and bounded, so $(X_n,X)\xrightarrow{D}(X,X)$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} Eg(X_n,X) = Eg(X,X)$.  But $Eg(X,X) = 0$, so we know $\lim_{n>0} d_P(Y_n,Y)=0,$ where $Y_n=h(X_n)$ and $Y=h(X).$ This implies $Y_n\xrightarrow P Y$.

ADDED NEXT DAY:  Grimmett's textbook has a clean and simple proof.  We want to show that for arbitrary $\delta>0$ we have $P(|Y_n-Y|>\delta)\to0$.  It suffices to show that for each $\eta>0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, $P(|Y_n-Y|>\delta)<\eta$.  So pick $K$ so large that $P(|X|>K)<\eta/2$, and observe that the function $h$ is uniformly continuous on $[-K,K]$, and hence there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|u|\le K$ and $|u-v|\le\epsilon$ together imply $|h(u)-h(v)|<\delta$. Thus, $P(|Y_n-Y|>\delta)<P(|X|>K) + P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\eta/2 + P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\eta$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.